# Ban reason remove

Tags: python

I made a module for Ban Reasons for a bot i have on chatango 
Here is my code

```
import os
import string

if not os.path.exists("banr.DB"):
  open("banr.DB","w").write("")

class banr:        

  def add_banreason(roomname, username, reason):
    roomname = roomname.lower()
    username = username.lower()
    if not roomname in banr.banr_database:
      banr.banr_database[roomname] = [[username,reason]]
    else:
      banr.banr_database[roomname].append([username,reason])

  def remove_banreason(roomname, username):
    roomname = roomname.lower()
    username = username.lower()
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
      data2 = list(banr.banr_database[roomname])
      if len(banr.banr_database[roomname]) <=1:
        del banr.banr_database[roomname]
        return(data2)
      else:
        usersname, reason = banr.banr_database[roomname]
        if username in usersname:
            banr.banr_database[roomname].remove([username])
            return(data2)

  def brrcheckall(roomname):
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
      if len(banr.banr_database) == 0:
        return ("there are no users that have ban reasons in anyrooms")
      elif len(banr.banr_database) == 1:
        return ("I have 1 room where users have ban reasons Room:- ~"+str(banr.banr_database))
      else:
        return ("I have "+str(len(banr.banr_database))+" rooms where users have ban reasons Rooms:- ~"+str(banr.banr_database))
    else:
      return ("I have "+str(len(banr.banr_database))+" rooms where users have ban reasons Rooms:- ~"+str(banr.banr_database))

  def brrcheckusers(roomname):
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
      if len(banr.banr_database[roomname]) == 0:
        return (str(list(banr.banr_database[roomname])))
      elif len(banr.banr_database[roomname]) == 1:
        return (str(list(banr.banr_database[roomname])))
      else:
        return (str(list(banr.banr_database[roomname])))
    else:
      return

  def brrcheckau(roomname):
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
      if len(banr.banr_database) == 0:
        return (str(list(banr.banr_database)))
      elif len(banr.banr_database) == 1:
        return (str(list(banr.banr_database)))
      else:
        return (str(list(banr.banr_database)))
    else:
      return (str(list(banr.banr_database)))


  def brrcheckroom(roomname):
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
      if len(banr.banr_database[roomname]) == 0:
        return ("I have "+str(len(banr.banr_database[roomname]))+" users that have ban reasons in this room Users:- ~"+str(list(banr.banr_database[roomname])))
      elif len(banr.banr_database[roomname]) == 1:
        return ("I have 1 user that has a ban reason in this room  Users:- ~"+str(list(banr.banr_database[roomname])))
      else:
        return ("I have "+str(len(banr.banr_database[roomname]))+" users that have ban reasons in this room Users:- ~"+str(list(banr.banr_database[roomname])))
    else:
      return ("there are no users that have ban reasons in this room")

  ### load the database
  def load():
    banr_database = {}
    with open("banr.DB","r") as t:
      data = t.read()
    if data != "":
      for l in data.split("\n"):
        a,b = l.split("):(",1)
        c = [w.split(")-(") for w in b.split("(:)")]
        banr_database[a] = c
    banr.banr_database = banr_database

  ### save the database
  def save():
    l = []
    for a,b in banr.banr_database.items():
      c = "(:)".join([")-(".join(w) for w in b])
      l.append(a+"):("+c)
    with open("banr.DB","w") as t:
      t.write("\n".join(sorted(l)))

banr.load()
```

I need help here

```
  def remove_banreason(roomname, username):
    roomname = roomname.lower()
    username = username.lower()
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
      data2 = list(banr.banr_database[roomname])
      if len(banr.banr_database[roomname]) <=1:
        del banr.banr_database[roomname]
        return(data2)
      else:
        usersname, reason = banr.banr_database[roomname]
        if username in usersname:
            banr.banr_database[roomname].remove([username])
            return(data2)
```

My problem is that i want to remove from the list inside a specific roomname which contains multiple users and reasons kinda looks like this below:

```
{roomname: [[username, reason], [username, reason], [username, reason]]}
```

I want to Remove a list from that list of lists using only the username 
If this isn't possible than i would like to be able to pull the reason for the username automatically everytime it goes to remove a username, that way all i have to do is type the username when i want to remove and it will match the username with the reason it has and use that reason with the username provided to remove the username and reason from the roomname

Also when i try without the reason i get

```
Error: list.remove(x) x not in list()
```

Comment: Can you restructure it to be a dict of dict? `{roomname: {username: reason, username:reason}, room2: {user: reason}}`. This will allow you to do simple lookups

Comment: `{roomname: {username1:[reason1, reason2], username2:[reason1,reason2,reason3]}}` would be another alternative.

Comment: Even if you don't take @Daenyth's suggestion, you should at least change your innner lists to tuples (```()``` instead of ```[]```)

Comment: hmm i havent thought of that can u provide an example using the code i provided but recoded to use dict of dict @Daenyth im not too good at using dicts

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a user could have multiple ban reasons. If you change your data structure to `{roomname: {username1:[reason1, reason2], username2:[reason1,reason2,reason3]}}` your remove ban reason method would be like:

```
def remove_banreason(roomname, username):
    roomname = roomname.lower()
    username = username.lower()
    if roomname in banr.banr_database:
        if username in banr.banr_database[roomname]
            del banr.banr_database[roomname][username]
    return banr.banr_database
```

Comment: -1 @scriptmonster as im not looking to make multi reasons >.> what Daenyth said is closer to what i want i just need him to show me how to reconstruct to dict of dict as ive never done a dict inside of a dict before

Comment: `bans[room][user] = reason`. (Check if room in bans first). You need to go follow some intro to python tutorials because this is extremely basic stuff

Comment: thanks although when i tried doing [][] it always acts funny when i asked my freind he said i couldnt do that so that was helpful to me  +1 Daenyth